# VM doesn't boot after drag and drop

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

After attempting to drag and drop a file from my Ubuntu host into my Windows 10 VM, (which crashed VirtualBox) the image seems to have become corrupted.

On booting, I immediately get the dreaded "black screen white cursor" and get no further.

None of the usual "bash F8" techniques are getting me into the bootup menu.

Is there anything I can do to attempt a recovery?

Comment: You could try creating a fresh VM using the same image. If that doesn't work, you could try booting the VM off windows iso and running recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the Windows ISO into a virtual optical drive and set the drive to the top of the boot order.

This then booted the VM into the Windows installation process from where I was able to `Repair Computer` then `Continue in Windows` (or similar).

The VM then booted and I was able to shut it down normally and it now boots just fine.

Comment: Thanks to [this comment](http://superuser.com/questions/1097941/vm-doesnt-boot-after-drag-and-drop?noredirect=1#comment1558000_1097941) by @user5226582 for pointing me in the right direction.